# Cant get full resolution on Second monitor with nvdia geforce 210 on 14.04

Tags: nvidia, 14.04, xorg, multiple-monitors, resolution

I am using two Samsung 1920x1080 monitors with my Ubuntu 14.04 machine having an nvdia geforce 210 graphic card.

The first monitor is connected to the VGA port and the second monitot to the DVI port with a VGA-to-DVI converter. The First monitor is showing full resolution (1920x1080) and the second is showing only 1024x768 resolution.

I have installed nvidia drivers from ***Ubuntu Additional Drivers***  but couldnt make it work.

Comment: Any solution for this? Having the same problem, un ubuntu 14.04 with GeForce 210.

Comment: I replaced the vga-to-dva converter with a dvi cable and it worked well.

Comment: Try this method, it worked for me. http://askubuntu.com/questions/712116/how-to-set-up-native-monitor-resolution-of-1680-%c3%97-1050-with-nvidia-geforce-210-o/855969#855969