# How to set up native monitor resolution of 1680 × 1050 with Nvidia Geforce 210 on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, multiple-monitors, display-resolution

I use a video card Nvidia Geforce 210.

According to [it's specs](http://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-210/specifications) it can run :Maximum Digital Resolution 2560x1600 and Maximum VGA Resolution 2048x1536.

I use Ubuntu 14.04 LTS with NVIDIA-Linux-x86-340.96.run driver instaled and activated and the maximum resolution I get is 1360x768 that is to narrow and 1152x864 that is to wide on both of my monitors (used as expanded):

1. Optiquest Q201wb 1680 x 1050
2. Iiyama prolite e2200ws 1680 × 1050

Can you give me an advice on how to make my resolution 1680x1050 permanent(not only until first reboot)?

Whith nouveau display driver it's the same thing as is with Nvidia driver 304.131

PS. I saw [this similar post][Cant get full resolution on Second monitor with nvdia geforce 210 on 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/487000/cant-get-full-resolution-on-second-monitor-with-nvdia-geforce-210-on-14-04)) but I don't think it's the same problem.

Output from `xrandr`

```
    Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 2304 x 864, maximum 8192 x 8192
DVI-I-0 connected primary 1152x864+1152+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768       60.0 +
   1360x768       60.0     59.8  
   1152x864       60.0* 
   800x600        72.2     60.3     56.2  
   680x384        60.0     59.8  
   640x480        59.9  
   512x384        60.0  
   400x300        72.2  
   320x240        60.1  
VGA-0 connected 1152x864+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768       60.0 +
   1360x768       60.0     59.8  
   1152x864       60.0* 
   800x600        72.2     60.3     56.2  
   680x384        60.0     59.8  
   640x480        59.9  
   512x384        60.0  
   400x300        72.2  
   320x240        60.1  
DVI-I-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  **;-)** I've asked one of our resident `xrandr` experts to have a look at your question.  As he's sleeping right now, don't expect an answer in the next 8 hours...

Comment: Thanks @Fabby I hope I will be worth your trust:). We will need the output of xrandr anyway, could you post it (a link to it) somewhere?

Comment: **Marius:**  Could you please go to a terminal by pressing [Ctrl][Alt][T] and type `xrandr`. Then [edit] your question and copy-paste the output of the command into your question so we can see what exact hardware you have. Then leave a comment @JacobVlijm.

Comment: Hello, Thank you for yout answears and Merry Christmas! I'll be able to do it only next week.

Comment: @JacobVlijm. Hello, I've edited my questions and added the code you asked for.

Comment: @dn-ʞɔɐq ɹW Hi again. I've done what you asked me..I gues there is no solution on this mather.

Comment: @JacobVlijm or maybe I shouldn't have put the dot in my previous comment?

Comment: @marius-ciclistu ah, sorry, missed it. will look into it tomorrow.

Comment: @JacobVlijm I gues there is no solution to my problem...

Comment: I still have the same issue after updating to kernel 4.4.0-36

Comment: @SimionAgavriloaei Hi. I saw that you have the same problem here http://askubuntu.com/questions/487000/cant-get-full-resolution-on-second-monitor-with-nvdia-geforce-210-on-14-04 . Did you find a solution?

Comment: @JacobVlijm Hi. I found my solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my problem by seeking on the internet the horizontal and vertical refresh rate for my monitors:

1.Optiquest Q201wb 1680 x 1050

Horizontal refresh rate 30-80 Hz

Vertical refresh rate 55-75 Hz

2.Iiyama prolite e2200ws 1680 × 1050

Horizontal refresh rate 31-82 Hz

Vertical refresh rate 56-75 Hz

Then by using Torben Gundtofte-Bruun's tutorial from here [How do I set the correct monitor resolution with Nvidia drivers for a monitor that does not send EDID?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100900/how-do-i-set-the-correct-monitor-resolution-with-nvidia-drivers-for-a-monitor-th) I've edited /etc/X11/xorg.conf file with

```
 sudo gedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

and I entered the values 31-80 Hz for

> HorizSync

and 56-75 Hz for

> VertRefresh

in the

> Section "Monitor"

part. The values from there were very different from the above.

After that , from Displays I could select the 16:10 ratio 1680x1050 resolution.
I'm verry happy now. Thank you Torben Gundtofte-Bruun.